# Permit pair on Uniswap for gasless swap on web3py

Tags: tokens, gas, web3.py

I've already successfully swapped tokens on uniswap using web3py so now i'm trying to use the permit function to approve my USDC via a signature, saving on gas fees for this approval state.

I've looked at the USDC/ETH pair contract from uniswap on etherscan at https://etherscan.io/token/0xb4e16d0168e52d35cacd2c6185b44281ec28c9dc#writeContract and found the permit function, I have to provide several parameters such as:

```
function permit(
address owner, 
address spender, 
uint value, 
uint deadline, 
uint8 v, 
bytes32 r, 
bytes32 s) 
external;
```

I can do the 4 first (until deadline) and have already seen these 3 letters (v,r,s) while signing my raw tx when doing a swap on web3py, but I'm stuck on how to integrate these letters values returned as you normally get them afterwards and not before signing the tx (hope to make sense here, correct me if I'm wrong of course).

coding part:

```
usdcpermit = router.functions.permit(myethaddress, myethaddress, USDCvalue, deadline, v, r, s)
```

Comment: The permit function is used by the LP token when removing liquidity, it is not used for a regular token swap.

Comment: It is when you have the permit function enable in the token such as USDC ect..

Comment: Do you have an example where it is used? I did take a look at v2 contract and the only use of permit function is related to liquidity provisioning, also it wasn't mentioned in the documentation nor the public examples. I haven't check the new v3 contract so perhaps it is a new thing there.